# Round *UP* float value to desired scale 1.1234 (scale:2) -> 1.13

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, rounding

- `scale` is number of digit after `.`
- if `scale` negative than number of digit before `.`

```py
round_up(0.12345, 3) == 0.124 
round_up(1554.3706592276444, 0) == 1555 
round_up(1554.3706592276444, 1) == 1554.4 
round_up(1554.3706592276444, 2) == 1554.38 
round_up(12345.123456789, 8) == 12345.12345679 

# Negative examples 
round_up(12345.123456789, -2) == 12400 
round_up(12345.123456789, -3) == 13000 
round_up(12345.123456789, -4) == 20000
```

Comment: While it is fine and encouraged to answer your own question to share knowledge, it should still be a **question**.

Comment: I'm open to any edits and suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

```py
from math import ceil, floor
from typing import Literal

def _round_to(to: Literal["up", "down"], value: Any, scale: int) -> float | int:
    """Round down a float value to the `to` float"""
    if scale > 0 and scale == len(str(value).split(".")[-1]):
        return value
    value = Decimal(str(value))  #  avoid floating-point arithmetic
    multiplier = 10**scale
    value = (floor if to == "down" else ceil)(value * multiplier) / multiplier
    return value if scale > 0 else int(value)


def round_down(value: float, scale: int = 0):
    """Round down a float value to the nearest small float

    Examples:
        >>> assert round_up(9.3, 2) == 9.30
        >>> assert round_down(-0.01, 1) == -0.1
        >>> assert round_down(4.15, 2) == 4.15
        >>> assert round_down(round_down(0.55, 2), 2) == 0.55
        >>> assert round_down(0.12345, 3) == 0.123
        >>> assert round_down(1554.3706592276444, 0) == 1554
        >>> assert round_down(1554.3706592276444, 1) == 1554.3
        >>> assert round_down(1554.3706592276444, 2) == 1554.37
        >>> assert round_down(12345.123456789, 8) == 12345.12345678
        >>> assert round_down(12345.123456789, -2) == 12300
        >>> assert round_down(12345.123456789, -3) == 12000
        >>> assert round_down(12345.123456789, -4) == 10000
        >>> assert round_down(11.0000000000000001, 2) == 11.0
        >>> assert round_down(11.000000000000001, 2) == 11.0
        >>> assert round_down(2.9076925e-05, 8) == 0.00002907
    """
    return _round_to("down", value, scale)


def round_up(value: float, scale: int = 0):
    """Round up a float value to the nearest great float

    Examples:
        >>> assert round_up(-0.01) == 0.0
        >>> assert round_up(-0.01, 1) == 0.0
        >>> assert round_up(4.15, 2) == 4.15
        >>> assert round_up(round_up(0.55, 2), 2)== 0.55
        >>> assert round_up(0.12345, 3) == 0.124
        >>> assert round_up(1554.3706592276444, 0) == 1555
        >>> assert round_up(1554.3706592276444, 1) == 1554.4
        >>> assert round_up(1554.3706592276444, 2) == 1554.38
        >>> assert round_up(12345.123456789, 8) == 12345.12345679
        >>> assert round_up(12345.123456789, -2) == 12400
        >>> assert round_up(12345.123456789, -3) == 13000
        >>> assert round_up(12345.123456789, -4) == 20000
        >>> assert round_up(11.0000000000000001, 2) == 11.0
        >>> assert round_up(11.000000000000001, 2) == 11.01
    """
    return _round_to("up", value, scale)
```

Comment: `round_up(4.15, 2)` gives `4.16`. Is that what you intended? Even more fun: `round_up(round_up(0.55, 2))` gives `0.57`.

Comment: Oh, no. Thank you for telling me, I fixed.